# How can I apply an onFocus and onBlur event to all inputs, select boxes and textareas within a form only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help,

How can I apply an onFocus and onBlur event to all inputs, select boxes and textareas within a form only.

I need the focused element's background changed to yellow and then back to white onBlur using jQuery.

```
<form id="form1">
<select id="routing">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="ASF">ASF</option>
    <option value="ASFA">ASFA</option>
    <option value="ASFB">ASFB</option>
    <option value="ASFC">ASFC</option>
    <option value="ASFE">ASFE</option>
    <option value="ZSFD">ZSFD</option>
</select>
<br>
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option>administrator</option>
    <option>web developer</option>
    <option>graphic artist</option>
    <option>IT professional</option>
    <option>other</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<br>
<textarea id="txtarea1"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
$('#form1 select, #form1 input, #form1 textarea').focus(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});

$('#form1 select, #form1 input, #form1 textarea').blur(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/RTASE/1/)

---

Or a shorter version:

```
$('#form1 select, #form1 input, #form1 textarea').on('focus blur', function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', $(this).is(':focus') ? "yellow" : "white");
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/RTASE/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use events delegation. You only need one listener on the form, `event.target` will give you the rest.